# Moodle - Get current user role

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

How to get current logged in user role and login activity?
And data not inserting into table.

I have created a table and fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
$var="SELECT * FROM `mdl_role` as er,`mdl_role_assignments` as era WHERE era.roleid=er.id && userid=$USER->id";
$data = mysql_query($var);
$rec = mysql_fetch_array($data);
echo $rec['shortname']."<br />";
```

I have joined these two tables and got the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user record using

`$user_object = get_record('user', 'id', $USER->id);`

In order to check if a user has a specific capability, you can use the get_context_instance function.

```
global $COURSE, $USER;

$context = get_context_instance(CONTEXT_COURSE,$COURSE->id);

if (has_capability('moodle/legacy:student', $context, $USER->id, false) ) {
echo "is Student<br/>";
}
if (has_capability('moodle/legacy:teacher', $context, $USER->id, false) ) {
echo "is Assitent Teacher<br/>";
}
if (has_capability('moodle/legacy:editingteacher', $context, $USER->id, false)) {
echo "is Teacher<br/>";
}
if (has_capability('moodle/legacy:admin', $context, $USER->id, false)) {
echo "is ADMIN<br/>";
}
```